# Regular expression to match text between curly brackets

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

Trying to extract the text between the first open and last close curly brackets from this code:

```
<script data-json='{"gr":{"template":77234,"body":"compact"},"model":"sedan"}' type="text/plain"></script>
```

I've tried using [.*?]|{.*?} but that only matched the following:
    `{"gr":{"template":77234,"body":"compact"}`

I need to get the following:
    `{"gr":{"template":77234,"body":"compact"},"model":"sedan"}`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using BeautifulSoup instead: select the `<script>` tag, then extract the `data-json` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = '''
<script data-json='{"gr":{"template":77234,"body":"compact"},"model":"sedan"}' type="text/plain"></script>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
script = soup.select('script[data-json]')
jsonData = script[0]['data-json']
print(jsonData)
```

Output:

```
{"gr":{"template":77234,"body":"compact"},"model":"sedan"}
```

Comment: I just did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try simple

```
'({.+})'
```

and then get the first group via `.group(1)` on the match